# Represent placeholder for inverse of a function in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am interested in solving integro-differential equations that not only contain functions of variables, but also inverse functions. In SymPy a function can be represented by `Function`:

```py
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
f = Function(x)
```

However I did not find an inverse function method. While `Function` has the method `inverse`, it is more specifically the multiplicative inverse.

Attempting to setup an equation and solve it to obtain a symbolic inverse is not implemented:

```py
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
f = Function(x)
solve(Eq(y, f))

NotImplementedError: 
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation y - f(x)
```

Is there a way to setup a symbolic inverse of a function in SymPy?